# Is there any way to use hibernate 6.1.x with spring boot 2.7.x where we want to use custom sessionFactory creation also

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

We are trying to migrate a legacy spring mvc application to spring boot 2.7.x
we are using hibernate 4.x in our application and we are trying to migrate it to hibernate 6.1.x
we are using **HibernateTransactionManager** and **sessionFactory** also.
is there any way to use hibernate 6 with spring boot 2.7.x

I tried to add hibernate 6.x , jakarata, spring-orm dependencies to my pom file.
but latest version of spring orm is having only hibernate5

`import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager`

`import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: No. As Spring 5 doesn't support Hibernate 6.x  nor the JakartaEE APIs. Why not just upgrade to Spring Boot 3 in the migration

Comment: Currently we are using java 11 and Because of some limitation we can not move to java 17 now. and spring boot 3 uses java 17. @M.Deinum